# onScroll React cannot trigger

Tags: reactjs, scroll

why if i using onScroll react version 16 cannot fire how to make it work. because i want using onScroll than onWheel?.

```
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._fireOnScroll = this.fireOnScroll.bind(this);
}

fireOnScroll() {
    console.log('Fire!');
}

componentDidMount() {
    const elem = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.elementToFire);
    elem.addEventListener('scroll', this._fireOnScroll, true);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    const elem = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.elementToFire);
    elem.removeEventListener('scroll', this._fireOnScroll);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div ref="elementToFire">
      <AnotherComponent imagesUrl={Array(100)}}>}
    </div>
</div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Please show your actual code. What you posted here isn't valid. ReactDom <-> ReactDOM and no class around the functions you showed.

Answer (score 3):

Your div is empty. `scroll` only fires if actual scrolling did happen.
So, your div needs to be smaller than its content and needs to show scrollbars.

See [this pen](https://codepen.io/dhilgarth/pen/VxeYPw?editors=0010#0) for a working example.

However, there is no reason for using a ref. Simply use `onScroll`:

```
<div style={{height: 75, width: 100, overflow:'scroll'}} onScroll={this.fireOnScroll}>
```

See [this pen](https://codepen.io/dhilgarth/pen/PeZwXj?editors=0010#0) for a working example.

Comment: in your code very simple and still didn't work for me. actualy i have more than 100 image to show and if iwant see image what i get in my body. so i need scroll but onScroll cannot fire.

Comment: You need to show your actual code if my answer doesn't help you. My answer shows working code, see the links.

Comment: In my situation, I had data to be fetched, so before it fetched `scroll-y` set already to null, and after it populated and scroll shows but it's not working/updating in DOM may be. Though in desktop browser it works without problem, but in mobile browser `onScroll` not firing.

Answer (score 0):

Your ref is not properly assigned to the div it should be
`<div ref = {this.elementToFire} >`
If not works then try

`const elem = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.elementToFire.current);`
 Also from the code you have given O guess you missed to create a ref object also

`this.elementToFire = React.createRef();`

Hope it will work